# TFBertForTokenClassification scoring only O labels on a NER task

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition

I'm using TFBertForTokenClassification to perform a NER task on the annotated corpus fo NER:
https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus.
The problem is that the O-Labels are the majority of all labels, then the accuracy is quite high as the model correctly predicts most of them.
So, when I try to predict the labels of a simple sentence, the network predict only the O Label for each token of the sentence, however in several tutorials in which it is used Pytorch (I am using Tensorflow), the predictions are good.
Probably there is a problem in my code, but I cannot figure out where is it.

The code is the following:

```py
# Import libraries
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import math
import numpy as np

from transformers import (
    TF2_WEIGHTS_NAME,
    BertConfig,
    BertTokenizer,
    TFBertForTokenClassification,
    create_optimizer)
```

```py
# Config
MAX_LEN= 128
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 32
VALID_BTCH_SIZE = 8
EPOCHS = 10
BERT_MODEL = 'bert-base-uncased'
MODEL_PATH = "model.bin"
TRAINING_FILE = "../input/entity-annotated-corpus/ner_dataset.csv"
TOKENIZER = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL, do_lower_case=True)
```

```py
# Create the padded input, attention masks, token type and labels
def get_train_data(text, tags):

    tokenized_text = []
    target_tags = []

    for index, token in enumerate(text):

        encoded_token = TOKENIZER.encode(
            token,
            add_special_tokens = False
        )

        encoded_token_len = len(encoded_token)

        tokenized_text.extend(encoded_token)
        target_tags.extend([tags[index]] * encoded_token_len)

    #truncation
    tokenized_text = tokenized_text[: MAX_LEN - 2]
    target_tags = target_tags[: MAX_LEN - 2]

    #[101] = [CLS] , [102] = [SEP]
    tokenized_text = [101] + tokenized_text + [102]
    target_tags = [0] + target_tags + [0]
    attention_mask = [1] * len(tokenized_text)
    token_type_ids = [0] * len(tokenized_text)

    #padding
    padding_len = int(MAX_LEN - len(tokenized_text))

    tokenized_text = tokenized_text + ([0] * padding_len)
    target_tags = target_tags + ([0] * padding_len)
    attention_mask = attention_mask + ([0] * padding_len)
    token_type_ids = token_type_ids + ([0] * padding_len)

    return (tokenized_text, target_tags, attention_mask,  token_type_ids)
```

```py
# Extract sentences from dataset
class RetrieveSentence(object):
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.n_sent = 1
        self.data = data
        self.empty = False
        function = lambda s: [(w, p, t) for w, p, t in zip(s["Word"].values.tolist(),
                                                           s["POS"].values.tolist(),
                                                           s["Tag"].values.tolist())]
        self.grouped = self.data.groupby("Sentence #").apply(function)
        self.sentences = [s for s in self.grouped]
    
    def retrieve(self):
        try:
            s = self.grouped["Sentence: {}".format(self.n_sent)]
            self.n_sent += 1
            return s
        except:
            return None
```

```py
# Load dataset and create one hot encoding for labels
df_data = pd.read_csv(TRAINING_FILE,sep=",",encoding="latin1").fillna(method='ffill')
Sentences = RetrieveSentence(df_data)

sentences_list = [" ".join([s[0] for s in sent]) for sent in Sentences.sentences]
labels = [ [s[2] for s in sent] for sent in Sentences.sentences]

tags_2_val = list(set(df_data["Tag"]))
tag_2_idx = {t: i for i, t in enumerate(tags_2_val)}

id_labels = [[tag_2_idx.get(l) for l in lab] for lab in labels]
sentences_list = [sent.split() for sent in sentences_list]

# I removed the sentence n 41770 because it gave index problems
del labels[41770]
del sentences_list[41770]
del id_labels[41770]
```

```py
encoded_text = []
encoded_labels = []
attention_masks = []
token_type_ids = []

for i in range(len(sentences_list)):

    text, labels, att_mask, tok_type = get_train_data(text = sentences_list[i], tags = id_labels[i])
    encoded_text.append(text)
    encoded_labels.append(labels)
    attention_masks.append(att_mask)
    token_type_ids.append(tok_type)
```

```py
# Convert from list to np array
encoded_text = np.array(encoded_text)
encoded_labels = np.array(encoded_labels)
attention_masks = np.array(attention_masks)
token_type_ids = np.array(token_type_ids)
```

```py
# Train Test split
X_train, X_valid, Y_train, Y_valid = train_test_split(encoded_text, encoded_labels, random_state=20, test_size=0.1)
Mask_train, Mask_valid, Token_ids_train, Token_ids_valid = train_test_split(attention_masks,token_type_ids ,random_state=20, test_size=0.1)
```

```py
# Aggregate the train and test set, then shuffle and batch the train set
def example_to_features(input_ids,attention_masks,token_type_ids,y):
  return {"input_ids": input_ids,
          "attention_mask": attention_masks,
          "token_type_ids": token_type_ids},y

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train,Mask_train,Token_ids_train,Y_train)).map(example_to_features).shuffle(1000).batch(32)
test_ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_valid,Mask_valid,Token_ids_valid,Y_valid)).map(example_to_features).batch(1)
```

```py
# Load TFBertForTokenClassification with default config
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL,num_labels=len(tags_2_val))
model = TFBertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL, from_pt=bool(".bin" in BERT_MODEL), config=config)
```

```py
# Add softmax layer, compute loss, optimizer and fit
model.layers[-1].activation = tf.keras.activations.softmax
model.summary()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=3, validation_data=test_ds)
```

```py
# Prediction. Spoiler: the label predicted are O-Label
sentence = "Hi , my name is Bob and I live in England"
inputs = TOKENIZER(sentence, return_tensors="tf")
input_ids = inputs["input_ids"]
inputs["labels"] = tf.reshape(tf.constant([1] * tf.size(input_ids).numpy()), (-1, tf.size(input_ids))) # Batch size 1
output = model(inputs)
```

The code is executed on a Kaggle notebook.
The transformer library version is 3.4.0

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `however in several tutorials` What tutorials are these?

Comment: [1](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert/)

[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqQ7rqRllIc&t=1692s)

[3](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1siYfyA34i4ZA4LdnOf9P_hR_THkJd6MA#scrollTo=yCSNlfzucPSF)

Comment: Did you find the reason for this behavior?